# How to keep an unevaluated math formula in one cell in Excel and evaluate it in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to have two cells in Excel:

In first of them (fx A1) I want to have an equation like `2 + 2`
In second (fx A2) I want to have the solution = 4.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First enter the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function eval(strng As String) As Variant
    eval = Evaluate(strng)
End Function
```

then in A2 enter:

**=eval(A1)**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to do exactly what you want using a worksheet function, this is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba) and this by design.

You can achieve this with VBa (and your post doesn't state using VBa or not so I assume not) or you `could` look for the old XLM GET.FORMULA() but VBa is better (and I know nothing of XLM)

You may be able to do something like

```
=FORMULATEXT(formulaCell)      

FORMULATEXT requires the morefunc.xll add-in.
```

[Source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/56079-how-reference-formula-another-cell-not-result.html)

---

However, as a work around and based on the exact example in your question, you could do the following (which works)

```
=SUM(LEFT(A1,1),RIGHT(A1,1))
```

This will only work when the formula is N+N (where N is 1 digit) but depending on how many rows of data you have, this may fit your needs!

[image]